# The "coords" attribute of the <area shape="rect"> tag is not in the "left,top,right,bottom" format.error in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, imagemap

I m getting this error when i tried to run my code in Firefox. Its working fine in IE. Actually i'm trying to achieve rollover effect on image by defining image map

```
<map name="planetmap"> 
    <area class="a1" shape="rect" coords="420,120,380,100" alt="Ring" href="#"/> 
    <area class="a2" shape="rect" coords="300,330,400,250" alt="Ring" href="#"/> 
    <area class="a3" shape="rect" coords="610,190,580,270" alt="Ring" href="#"/> 
    <area class="a4" shape="rect" coords="450,250,550,400" alt="Ring" href="#"/>
</map>
```

Please help me to fix this issue when i mouse over on image nothing is opening in Firefox.

Comment: <map name="planetmap"> \
 <area class="a1" shape="rect" coords="420,120,380,100" alt="Ring" href="#"/> <area class="a2" shape="rect" coords="300,330,400,250" alt="Ring" href="#"/> <area class="a3" shape="rect" coords="610,190,580,270" alt="Ring" href="#"/> <area class="a4" shape="rect" coords="450,250,550,400" alt="Ring" href="#"/> \
</map> \

Comment: With the code you've provided, there's no expectation that anything would happen. If you expect a rollover effect, then you must be using a plugin, or some javascript. Please provide more information.

Comment: Is it really that hard to understand that error? 420 > 380 while left < right ...

Comment: its working in IE but not in chrome and firefox

Answer (score 5):

Look at the error. "left, top, right bottom": in the image map coordinate system, "0,0" is the top left corner. So the 1st value must be smaller than the 3rd, and the 2nd value must be smaller than the 4th.

```
<area class="a1" shape="rect" coords="420,120,380,100" alt="Ring" href="#"/>
<area class="a2" shape="rect" coords="300,330,400,250" alt="Ring" href="#"/>
<area class="a3" shape="rect" coords="610,190,580,270" alt="Ring" href="#"/>
<area class="a4" shape="rect" coords="450,250,550,400" alt="Ring" href="#"/>
```

In the 1st one, 380 < 420 and 100 < 120. Both are wrong.
In the 2nd one, 250 < 330.
In the 3rd one, 580 < 610.
The 4th one looks correct.

Three of the four areas have invalid numbers, and generally are not even consistent with each other.

Comment: its still not working.Image is in the slide.image is also having a script on it and while using the same code is working fine on stand alone image.

Comment: I can only speak to what is wrong with the HTML  you've posted. If there are other problems then you need to provide more information.